# PHP not exiting loop

Tags: php, loops, break

Im trying to return some data from php based on time. ie if the current time is greater that the publish time then only the post data should be sent to the user else he should be told that's its scheduled.. the problem is the even if the condition is met it still executes the loop and gives my the 'success' result.any idea how to overcome this?

```
$sql = "Select posts.post_title,posts.author_name,posts.publish_date,posts.post_content,comments.name,comments.comment,comments.time_posted "
        . "from posts left join comments "
        . "on posts.id=comments.post_id "
        . "where posts.id=$data->id "
        . "LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error() . $sql);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $index = 0;
    if ($count >= 1) {
        $temp = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            if (strtotime($data->now) > strtotime($row['publish_date'])) {
                if ($index == 0) {
                    $results[$index]['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
                    $results[$index]['author_name'] = $row['author_name'];
                    $results[$index]['publish_date'] = $row['publish_date'];
                    $results[$index]['post_content'] = $row['post_content'];

                    $temp[$index]['name'] = $row['name'];
                    $temp[$index]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
                    $temp[$index]['time_posted'] = $row['time_posted'];
                } else {
                    $temp[$index]['name'] = $row['name'];
                    $temp[$index]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
                    $temp[$index]['time_posted'] = $row['time_posted'];
                }
                $index++;
            } else {
                $response['status'] = 'Scheduled';
                $response['message'] = 'Data present';
                break;
            }


        }
        $results[0]['comments'] = $temp;
        $response['status'] = 'Success';
        $response['message'] = 'Data present';
        $response['results'] = $results;

    } else {
        $response['status'] = '404';
        $response['message'] = 'Post does not exist';
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Look at the 4 lines immediately after the `while` loop. As long as your query returns a result, you're always reporting success!

Answer (score 0):

so i managed to solve it by just using a flag variable

```
$flag = true;
    if ($count >= 1) {
        $temp = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            if ((strtotime($data->now) > strtotime($row['publish_date'])) == true) {
                if ($index == 0) {
                    $results[$index]['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
                    $results[$index]['author_name'] = $row['author_name'];
                    $results[$index]['publish_date'] = $row['publish_date'];
                    $results[$index]['post_content'] = $row['post_content'];

                    $temp[$index]['name'] = $row['name'];
                    $temp[$index]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
                    $temp[$index]['time_posted'] = $row['time_posted'];
                } else {

                    $temp[$index]['name'] = $row['name'];
                    $temp[$index]['comment'] = $row['comment'];
                    $temp[$index]['time_posted'] = $row['time_posted'];
                }
                $index++;
            } else {
                $flag = false;
            }
        }
        if ($flag == false) {
            $response['status'] = 'Scheduled';
            $response['message'] = 'Data present';
        } else {
            $results[0]['comments'] = $temp;
            $response['status'] = 'Success';
            $response['message'] = 'Data present';
            $response['results'] = $results;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter your condition is met or not,you are always initializing status to success($response['status'] = 'Success';).
You need to move this line to code block which executes when condition is met.